# $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, $x_ix_j\in X$ whenever $1\leq i \leq j \leq n$. Then $X\leq G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty finite subset of a group $G$; say $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Suppose that $x_ix_j\in X$ whenever $1\leq i \leq j \leq n$.
Prove that $X\leq G$.

I have done the following:
(i) $x_i^m\in X$ for every positive integer $m$ and for every $i=1,\dots,n$.
(ii) For every $i=1,\dots,n$, $x_i$ has finite order and $x_i^{-1}\in X$.
(iii) If $x_iX=X$, then $x_i^{-1}X=X$.

I want to prove by induction on $j$ that for every $j=1,\dots,n$, $x_jX=X$.
For $j=1$, it is clear since $x_1x_k\in X$ for every $k\geq 1$ and hence $x_1X\subseteq X$.
Define $f:X\rightarrow x_1X$ by $f(x)=x_1x$. Then $f$ is one-to-one. Hence $|x_1X|\leq |X|\leq |x_1X|$ hence $x_1X=X$.

Suppose that $x_lX=X$.
I have no idea how to prove $x_{l+1}X=X$ since I still can't verify that $x_{l+1}x_k\in X$ for $l+1>k$.

If this is proven, then we have $X^2=X$. Since $G$ is finite, $X\leq G$.

Comment: Is $G$ a group?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, it is.

Comment: Take the subgroup of $G$ generated by $X$ and show that is this group has the required form.

Comment: You have closed under multiplication and you have shown that all inverses are in there. Together with it being non-empty, that should give exactly the axioms for $X$ to be a subgroup of $G$; you might want to look these up?

Comment: @Bemte No the closure is still not completed since the closure in the question just holds for $x_ix_j$ where $1\leq i \leq j \leq n$. For example the closure for $x_2x_1$ is not guaranteed from the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inductive assumption is that $x_kX = X$ for $1 \le k  \le l$.

So by (iii), which you have proven, for any such $k$ we have $x_k^{-1}X = X$, and hence in particular $x_k^{-1}x_{l+1}^{-1} = (x_{l+1}x_k)^{-1} \in X$.

So by your property (ii), $x_{l+1}x_k \in X$, and you are done.